# Remove language code from URL

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

For example, with example.com/en/apple/12/article/11/23, in `hook_init()` `arg(0)` returns "apple," as I expect; in `hook_boot()` it returns `en` which is language prefix of English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `hook_boot()` is invoked too early in the bootstrap process, which means:

1. Not all the modules are loaded, including the Locale module that is the one that alter the path, and the reason why `arg(0)` returns "apple" in your example, when called in `hook_init()`.
2. The language has not been set; it is initialized during the `DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_LANGUAGE` phase, while `hook_boot()` is invoked during the `DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_PAGE_CACHE` phase.
3. The call to [drupal_path_initialize()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_path_initialize/7), which alters `$_GET['q']` with `$_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path($_GET['q']);` is done during the `DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL` phase, which is the last bootstrap phase.

Differently, `hook_init()` is invoked as last step done in the `DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL` phase, which means all modules are loaded, the language has been set, and `drupal_path_initialize()` has been already called.

As side note, [`hook_boot()` has been removed from Drupal 8](http://drupal.org/node/1909596); if you are using it, you will need to change your code. Using `hook_init()` is a possible alternative, since it is still used in Drupal 8.

Comment: so I should call `drupal_path_initialize()` manually in `hook_boot()`?

Comment: If you call `drupal_path_initialize()` in `hook_boot()` you would get an error about a not defined function; as per first point, it would not make sense doing it because the module that alters the result is still not loaded.